# Best practice for securing an admin panel for a custom cms?

Tags: node.js, security, content-management-system, webserver, admin

I am currently building a custom cms system with the MEAN stack. I also want to have a backend web based admin panel for it, but I also want it to be as secure as possible. In the past, when I've build php-based scripts, I simply made a `/admin` route where the user would be presented with a login page and then allowed to proceed to use administration functions on the cms. However, by analysing my web server access logs, I've noticed a lot of requests to common admin routes such as `/wp-admin` or `/administration` and even my own `/admin` route from wannabe hackers, even when those websites did not have lots of traffic.

I've been thinking of using a different approach this time, specifically setting up a separate node app for administration purposes and putting it on a completely different port (i.e. 2123) and then setting up the server's firewall to only allow certain ip blocks to access that port. This way, even if the attacker does a portscan on my webserver, they would only be able to see the default ports 80 and 443. Would this be a good solution to secure my app or are there any better approaches?

Comment: I'm interested in this too, albeit I think it will be locked for opinion rather than a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Serving the admin interface from a different origin (origin being protocol+domain+port together) is indeed the best practice. One reason is what you mentioned, you can implement separate network level protection, for example you can restrict clients by their IP addresses.

Another reason is because this way, base app and the admin app will be separated in browsers by the same origin policy. Coming from different origins, they will not share cookies (session), broswer stores (localStorage, etc.) will be separate and so on. For example, if these two apps were on the same protocol, domain and port, one single XSS in the base app could be exploited to gain access to admin data or functionality - this is not the case with different origins.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a VPN and make remote users connect with the VPN, and only allow local network access to the admin panel

Or put a WAF like modsecurity in front of your web server

Your IP restriction idea isn't a bad one though